# Angular 2 POST JSON to C# API

Tags: c#, json, angular, api, post

Good Evening Community,

I am having problems to post data to a C# Api from Angular 2 POST methods. Practically I need to send a JSON object to the API. Below is the API POST method that is the endpoint.

```
[HttpPost]
public Boolean Update(BoRole role, Guid accessToken)
{
    CheckUserSuperadmin(accessToken);

    string JsonContent = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    var roleEntity = BaseDependencies.RoleManager.GetRoleById(role.Id);
    roleEntity.Name = role.Name;
    roleEntity.AuthorizedThreshold = role.AuthorizedThreshold;

    BaseDependencies.RoleManager.UpdateRole(roleEntity);

    return true;
}
```

The following is my Angular 2 service, with the POST method.

```
// Update the Role
updateRole(role: Role, accessToken: string): any {  
    const body: any = JSON.stringify(role);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    const url = this.serverUrl + '/api/Role/Update?role=' + body + '&accessToken=' + accessToken;

    return this.http.post(url, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

To explain better, I am trying to send a JSON object to this API, but whenever I try to POST to the API the *role* object remains null, never tried to POST data this way. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the Api to get only one get one body

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]AddRequest value)
```

In my case the class

> AddRequest

Have all the body structure that I need, in your case create one class that C# can automap (same names) and the rest is history in C#

At Angular

> const url = this.serverUrl + '/api/Role/Update?role=' + body +
>   '&accessToken=' + accessToken;

change it for

> const url = this.serverUrl + '/api/CONTROLLERNAME';

C# will detect that is a Post Request and map it to the right Http Call